# How to specify Access Token in PostMan

Tags: json, authorization, access-token, postman, bearer-token

I have imported a JSON file in to postman and the JSON Body is requesting Authorization Bearer value for a specific parameter. How to set a value to the parameter. Currently its undefined. Please refer the below JSON code and image.

`"name": "Pos_TC-Name",
                    "event": [
                        {
                            "listen": "test",
                            "script": {
                                "type": "text/javascript",
                                "exec": [
                                    "tests[\"Status code is 200\"] = responseCode.code === 200;"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "request": {
                        "url": "http://localhost:52586/api/Patient/7",
                        "method": "GET",
                        "header": [
                            {
                                "key": "Content-Type",
                                "value": "application/json",
                                "description": ""
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "Authorization",
                                "value": "Bearer {{NurseAdminToken}}",
                                "description": ""
                            }
                        ],
                        "body": {
                            "mode": "raw",
                            "raw": ""
                        },
                        "description": ""
                    },
                    "response": []
                },`

[image: Issue]

Comment: You have to define the variable as a `global` under `"Manage Environments"` You click on the "Setting Wheel" top right half of the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the variable as a `global` under `Manage Environments` You click on the "Settings Wheel" top right half of the window. Then you select/switch to the environment where you defined the global (the drop down menu next to the setting wheel).